# Errors when trying to interface Android with Arduino

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a project trying to get my Samsung Galaxy S2 to interface with the Arduino Mega ADK for Android and I'm getting a bunch of errors.

I've followed directions given here: http://stream.tellart.com/controlling-arduino-with-android/ to the letter. And I've tried running their [examples](http://sandbox.tellart.net/apa/Tellart-Android-Processing-Examples.zip)

Specifically the "TapOn" Example (which should allow me to control an LED connected to Arduino from my Android). But each time I run it I get errors on both the processing code for the Android and the arduino code.

Arduino Errors:
AndriodAccessory has not been declaired

```
AndroidAccessory.cpp:38: error: 'AndroidAccessory' has not been declared
AndroidAccessory.cpp:43: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AndroidAccessory' with no type
AndroidAccessory.cpp: In function 'int AndroidAccessory(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*)':
AndroidAccessory.cpp:43: error: only constructors take base initializers
AndroidAccessory.cpp: At global scope:
AndroidAccessory.cpp:54: error: 'AndroidAccessory' is not a class or namespace
AndroidAccessory.cpp: In function 'void powerOn()':
AndroidAccessory.cpp:56: error: 'max' was not declared in this scope
AndroidAccessory.cpp:57: error: 'delay' was not declared in this scope
AndroidAccessory.cpp: At global scope:
AndroidAccessory.cpp:60: error: 'AndroidAccessory' is not a class or namespace
AndroidAccessory.cpp:60: error: 'byte' was not declared in this scope
AndroidAccessory.cpp:61: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
AndroidAccessory.cpp:71: error: 'AndroidAccessory' is not a class or namespace
AndroidAccessory.cpp:71: error: variable or field 'sendString' declared void
AndroidAccessory.cpp:71: error: 'byte' was not declared in this scope
AndroidAccessory.cpp:71: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
AndroidAccessory.cpp:71: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
AndroidAccessory.cpp:82: error: 'AndroidAccessory' is not a class or namespace
AndroidAccessory.cpp:82: error: 'byte' was not declared in this scope
AndroidAccessory.cpp:83: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
```

Android/Processing Errors: 
Error from inside Android tools

```
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
No AIDL files to compile.
No RenderScript files to compile.
Generating resource IDs...
Generating BuildConfig class.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\AndriodSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:705: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\AndriodSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:718: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I don't understand whats wrong and why I'm getting these errors when I haven't changed any of the code from the samples. Also I can write programs for the arduino and android independently of each other, and they work fine... I only get the errors when I want the two to communicate with each-other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code has no library to work with. For me that meant roaming the internet till I found the correct libraries. I would try the following:

- Make sure you have the latest [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)
- Download the libraries, probably [this](http://labs.arduino.cc/uploads/ADK/GettingStarted/ArduinoADK-beta-001.zip).

Although if you want just try the step by step [here](http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/AccessoryMode).